# What is the best way to fetch data when it is only entered in View?

Tags: swiftui, init

When View opens, I need to fetch data from api. If I use to init like this;

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
       fetchDataFunc()
    }

    var body: some View {
         ...
    }
}
```

When the application is opened, inits in all vievs are running. But I just want the only entered view to init.

If I use to .onApppear like this;

```
    struct ContentView: View {

        List(viewModel.values) { value in
            NavigationLink(destination: ProjectDetailView()) {
              CellView(value: value)
           }
         }.onAppear{
             fetchDataFunc()
          }
     }
```

The problem here is that .onApppear works every time you navigate back. The list goes back to the top when navigate back. What is the best way solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all a view should never fetch data directly its the view models job.

```
   struct ContentView: View {

    List(viewModel.values) { value in
        NavigationLink(destination: ProjectDetailView()) {
          CellView(value: value)
       }
     }.onAppear{
         viewModel.fetchDataFuncIfNeeded()
      }
 }
```

and in the fetchDataFuncIfNeeded you can

```
  fetchDataFuncIfNeeded(){
  if self.shouldFetchData == true{
   self.fetchDataFunc()
    }
   }
```

so just update viewModel.shouldFetchData when navigate back or forward.